# Identity 2.0 Invalid Login Attempt

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

For some reason I am yet to discover, but after a successful registration and activation, I cannot login with the email address, instead I get an error "Invalid login attempt".

As ASP.NET Identity 2.0 has improved with the use of Email login, I have modified the registration form to actually store a true username as the existing registration just seemed to duplicate by storing Username with the email address.

Please see below the standard code that comes with `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre'` following the creation of an empty ASP.NET Web Application (MVC) project:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
```

My function is now as follows:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { TitleId = model.TitleId, SexId = model.SexId, Forename = model.Forename, Surname = model.Surname, UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, JoinDate = System.DateTime.Now };
```

As you can see UserName is now receiving a value from a form. This is all well and good except now I can't logon after registration and activation. The only work round is to modify the record by putting the value from the Email field into the UserName field which just seems daft.

Can somebody please advise as to what I might have missed?

Comment: You nee more than just one change. See my blogpost about that: http://marcinjuraszek.com/2014/03/asp-net-identity-2-0-0-username-and-email-separation.html

Comment: Thank you, I've read that article, it is to modify the login to user UserName instead of Email. But I want to login as Email, but also have Email and UserName as separate values. I noticed you linked to another article which should address my issue but the code is different to my Login action, the code suggest `var user = await UserManager.FindByNameOrEmailAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);` but my Login action uses `var result = await SignInHelper.PasswordSignIn(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to modify `SignInHelper.PasswordSignIn` method. By default it uses `FindByNameAsync` to check if user with given name exists:

```
public async Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignIn(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout)
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
    // (...)
```

change it to use `FindByEmailAsync`:

```
    var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(userName);
```

You can find `SignInHelper` class in *AppCode\IdentityConfig.cs` file.

Comment: Thank you very much `var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);` did the trick :-)

Comment: sir would u please give me clear instruction where i need to add the above function called PasswordSignIn() i add the same function in ApplicationSignInManager  class under but getting error.

Comment: I'm having this issue when using `AddDefaultUI`, and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 10):

In class **AccountController.cs**, method: `public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)`.
Modified this:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

To this:

```
try
{
    var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.Email.Equals(model.Email)).Single(); // where db is ApplicationDbContext instance
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
    // the user is not exist
}
```

The reason is `UserName` and `UserEmail` have different values but method `PasswordSignInAsync` only uses `UserName` to check for log in.

Comment: You are true, you saved my day. by default the identity generated views and SignInManager are different. The view require the email and the SingInManager.PasswordSignInAsync require Username.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue but found the solution to be a combination of both the accepted answer by Marcin and the answer by Hai. In `AccountController.cs` you need to use `FindByEmailAsync()`, instead of `FindByNameAsync()`, then use `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()` but use the value of `user.UserName` as the first argument (as long as `user` is not null), instead of `model.Email`. So a complete answer, based on the current boiler plate code, would be something like this:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        // (...) ModelState.IsValid, etc

        string user_name = ""; // in case 'user' is null (user not found)
        var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);

        if (user != null)
        {
            user_name = user.UserName;

            if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
            {
                // (...) Require the user to have a confirmed email before they can log on, etc
            }
        }

        // don't use model.Email below, use the value from user.UserName (if user not null)
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user_name, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            // (...)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try change to bool value in Startup.cs file in your project. "true->false"
In this line,             `services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)`

Comment: This was my issue. Not sure what happened because I was able to sign in before.

Answer (score 2):

Try To Edit The "RequireConfirmedAccount" Option from "true" to "false", it worked with me, in the program class.

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default authentication code generate , in Startup file you may see below code :

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<addition>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

the code forces you to use email confirm and if you didn't do that earlier you get "Invalid login attempt" error

Answer (score 0):

it works if you have confirmed email, you can just change the EmailConfirmed column values to True if all your users have not confirmed email