# ASP.Net identity gives 'invalid login attempt' when logging in after programmatically changing the password

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I've added .Net identity 2.0 to my Blazor server app, and it's all been working fine. I can register new users, log in, use `AuthorizeView`, etc just fine. I've built a user admin page that allows me to update user details such as username, add/remove from roles, and that's all good too.

Last night I added a 'change password' function to the User Edit dialog. I have two password fields, and if they're both equal I run the following code on the dialog submit button:

```
async Task Save()
{
    bool success = true;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) && password.Equals(passwordConfirm))
    {
        success = await userService.SetUserPasswordAsync(User, password);
    }
    else
    {
        success = await userService.UpdateUserAsync(User, selectedRoles);
    }

    if( success )
        MudDialog.Close(DialogResult.Ok(true));
}
```

The userService is a scoped service which manages various stuff around the UserManager and who's logged in etc. The UserService.SetUserPassword method looks like this:

```
    public async Task<bool> SetUserPasswordAsync(AppIdentityUser user, string password)
    {
        string token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);

        var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, password);

        return result.Succeeded;
    }
```

The token is returned, and the `ResetPasswordAsync` call succeeds. Salted password in the Users table in the DB updates. So all good at that point.

However, if I log out, and try and log back in with the email and new password, I get '`Invalid Login Attempt`'. Tried various things, but cannot figure it out. So two questions:

- Anyone got any idea what's wrong?
- Any ideas on how I can debug this to figure out what's going wrong? I
  don't know if the password isn't saving correctly, or if the user is
  somehow being corrupted when I reset the password, or something else.

The app is compiled against .Net 6 preview-7. Full Code is here, if it helps:

https://github.com/Webreaper/Damselfly/blob/develop/Damselfly.Web/Shared/UserDialog.razor
https://github.com/Webreaper/Damselfly/blob/develop/Damselfly.Web/Shared/UserManagement.razor
https://github.com/Webreaper/Damselfly/blob/develop/Damselfly.Core/Services/UserService.cs

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so it turned out that this was caused because I'd used the 'Edit User' screen to change the username from my email address to something else. This broke the `SignInHelper`'s user look-up.

The fix is to change the `SignInHelper` to look for either email *or* username - so the same as in this issue: [Identity 2.0 Invalid Login Attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614121/identity-2-0-invalid-login-attempt)